# Regular Expression for Percentage of marks

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex that matches percentage for marks

For example if we consider few percentages

```
1)100%
2)56.78%
3)56 78.90%
4)34.6789%
```

The matched percentages should be

```
100%
56.78%
34.6789%
```

I have made an expression `"\\d.+[\\d]%"` but it also matches for `56 78.90%` which I don't want.

If anyone knows such expression please share

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?%
```

This should do it for you.

For more stringent test use,

```
\b(?<!\.)(?!0+(?:\.0+)?%)(?:\d|[1-9]\d|100)(?:(?<!100)\.\d+)?%
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zsNIrG/2

Comment: @DoNhuVy use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?%` there as it is not java spcific http://regexr.com/3aumq

Comment: Thank you for the above explain. But I see your pattern still match: `56 78.90%`. Is there something wrong?

Comment: @DoNhuVy yes m not sure if OP wants it or not.A simple addtion of anchors will do it.`^\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$` with `m` flag

Comment: @vks yes u are correct ,but if i pass alone 100 then it wont work

Comment: this includes minus numbers- have you got a suggestion for excluding any values prefixed with `-`?

Comment: @Jamie a simple lookbehind should do it....'(?<!-)'

Answer (score 5):

You haven't double-escaped your dot, which means it's a wildcard for any character, including whitespace.

Use something like:

```
 ┌ integer part - any 1+ number of digits
 |   ┌ dot and decimal part (grouped)
 |   |┌ double-escaped dot
 |   ||  ┌ decimal part = any 1+ number of digits
 |   ||  |    ┌ 0 or 1 greedy quantifier for whole group
 |   ||  |    |
"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?%"
```

For instance:

```
String[] inputs = { "100%", "56.78%", "56 78.90%", "34.6789%" };
Matcher m = null;
for (String s: inputs) {
    m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find())
        System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: 100%
Found: 56.78%
Found: 78.90%
Found: 34.6789%
```

**Note**

This still matches the 3rd input, but only the last part.

If you want the 3rd input to just not match, you can surround your pattern with input boundaries, such as `^` for start of input, and `$` for end of input.

That would become: `"^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?%$"`

Or, you can simply invoke `Matcher#matches` instead of `Matcher#find`.

**Next step**

You may want to do *something* with the numerical value you're retrieving.

In this case, you can surround your pattern with a group (`"(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)%"`) and invoke either `Double.parseDouble` or `new BigDecimal(...)` on your back-reference:

- `Double.parseDouble(m.group(1))`
- `new BigDecimal(m.group(1))`

Answer (score 5):

**^((100)|(\d{1,2}(.\d*)?))%$**

Check this regular expression here: https://regex101.com/r/Ou3mJI/2

You can use this regular expression. It is valid for:

1. 0 to 100 inclusive
2. With and without decimal places

Below are valid values:

100% is valid
99.802% is valid
98.7% is valid
57% is valid
0% is valid

This regular expression invalidates below values:

1. Negative numbers
2. Number > 100
3. Number with spaces

Invalid value examples:

-1% 
99.989%
101%
56 78.90%

Hope this will help!

Comment: This same expression works for JavaScript as well https://regex101.com/r/O0SJjc/1

Comment: this was great, but didn't capture any values if it was in an alphanumeric string i.e. `"this is 15% lower"` does not match `15%`

Comment: Watch out for that dot, is not a dot it's any character.

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx `\\d+(\\.?\\d+)?%` would work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Robin this does answer the question.Why do you think it doesnt?

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to @vks for this answer, but I was looking for a regex that matched:

- Positive values between 0% - 100%
- No negative values
- In any given string

This includes a negative lookahead `(?<!-)` which excludes minus numbers.

```
\b(?<!-)(?<!\.)(?!0+(?:\.0+)?%)(?:\d|[1-9]\d|100)(?:(?<!100)\.\d+)?%
```