# Regex to match all types of percentage

Tags: python, regex

I have some % cases as the follow -

```
12.02
16.59
81.61%
45
24.812
51.35
19348952
88.22
0
000
021
.85%
100
```

I want to match all the percentages type except anything larger than 100.
Expected Output:

```
12.02
16.59
81.61
45
24.812
51.35

88.22
0
000
21
.85
100
```

I have tried ([Regular Expression for Percentage of marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072184/regular-expression-for-percentage-of-marks)). But this one fails to get all the cases that I want. Also, I am replacing the non-match with empty string. So my code in python looks like like this -

```
pattern=r'(\b(?<!\.)(?!0+(?:\.0+)?%)(?:\d|[1-9]\d|100)(?:(?<!100)\.\d+)?$)'
df['Percent']=df['Percent'].astype(str).str.extract(pattern)[0]
```

Many thanks.

Edit: The solution (by @rv.kvetch) matches most of the edge cases except the 0 ones but I can work with that limitation. The original post had requirement of not matching 0 case or 0%.

Comment: the majority of the inputs don't have the % suffix, is that intentional?

Comment: no. That's how they are in the dataset. I only copied a  few.

Comment: btw you can add a `%?` in regex to match an optional % symbol at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably very close but looks like this is working for me so far:

`^(?:0{0,})((?:[1-9]{1,2}|100)?(?:\.\d+)?)%?$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtTAPf/1)

---

#### Description

###### First non-capturing group

- `(?:0{0,})` - non-capturing group which matches a leading 0, that appears
  zero or more times.

###### First capture group

- `(?:[1-9]{1,2}|100)?` - Optional, non-capturing group which matches the digits `1-9` one to two times, to essentially cover the range 1-99. Then an *or* condition so we also cover 100. This group is made optional by `?` to cover cases like .24, which is still a valid percentage.
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - Optional, non-capturing group which matches the fractional part, e.g. `.123`. This is optional because numbers like 20 are valid percentage values by themselves.

###### Last non-capturing group

- `%?` - finally, here we match the optional trailing percent (%) symbol that can come at the end.

### Update

Here is a *non-regex* approach that should be more efficient than a regex approach. This also covers edge cases like `.0` that the regex currently hasn't been updated to handle:

```py
string = """
12.02
16.59
81.61%
45
24.812
51.35
19348952
88.22
0
000
.0%
021
.85%
100
150
1.2.3
hello world
"""

for n in string.split('\n'):
    try:
        x = float(n.rstrip('%'))
    except ValueError: # invalid numeric value
        continue
    # Check if number is in the range 0..100 (non-inclusive of 0)
    if 0 < x <= 100:
        print(x)
```

Comment: It matches the 0 or 0 cases as well..anyway you could exclude those as well..?

Comment: yep, just updated. looks like it does exclude them now. at least, it's not included in the first group.

Comment: But it does still capture ones like `.0%` - so I might need to fix that

Comment: Updated to add a description with the breakdown of the regex

Comment: I think I could work with this 0 case limitation as this solution still matches most of the edge cases.  I will mark this as answer after editing the question. Thanks

Comment: why can't r'\d+\.\d+%' be used to find the percentage data?

Comment: that could, very easily. I think a no-regex approach as mentioned by @Hirusha Fernando is likely more efficient also. But I think OP had specific requirements for this - for example, use regex to match only percentages in the range 1-100 (but `\d+\.\d+%` would of course would get you values outside this range. It depends I guess if you wanted to implement the validation outside of regex.

Comment: @GoldenLion I already tried that one before asking here but as rv.kvetch mentioned it fails to catch a lot of edge cases. I actually tried to post most of the unique ones but there are others cases as well that would not be matched.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can do it without using regex.

```py
nums = ['12.02'
'16.59',
'81.61%',
'45',
'24.812',
'51.35',
'19348952',
'88.22',
'0',
'000',
'021',
'.85%',
'100']

for n in nums:
  x = n.sptrip('%')
  x = int(x)
  if x <= 100:
    print(n)
```